# SCSS @include mixin won't compile in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, sass, mixins

I'm using SASS(.scss) on a rails (3.2.13) project and use variables & mixins for my media queries like so:

```
$desk-wide-start:   1100px  !default;

@mixin media-query($media-query) {
  @if $media-query == desk-wide{
    @media only screen and (min-width: $desk-wide-start) { @content; }
  }
}

// I include the mixin like so

@include media-query (desk-wide) {
  margin-top: 0; 
}
```

This site is running and working fine live, but I have been working on it locally (Lets call this code B) and made a few changes and now my media queries (mixins) have stopped working (they appear to NOT be compiling). If I write a @media query, this will work however.

I rewound my changes through Git to the code I last deployed to the live site (lets call this code A), and the mixins worked, I swapped back to my changes (code B) and then back to the working code (code A) and they had stopped working on this as well.

I get no Rails errors, and I have hard refreshed / cleared the cache on both Chrome and Firefox (latest stable).

Any ideas what could be causing the mixins to not compile / work?

So far i've tried rolling back in Git (see above) and updating the sass-rails gem to the latest version, I can't think what else may be causing it.

Comment: How are you calling the mixin?  You're not using it to do imports, are you?  How does the compiled CSS look?

Comment: Updated the question to show how I include them. Everything is compiled into 'application.css' by the assets pipeline. @cimmanon

Comment: Yes, but what's the *contents* of the CSS file?

Comment: @cimmanon It doesn't compile the mixin, just appears to 'skip' it. But rails doesn't error like it would if there was a missing bracket (in fact, if I remove a bracket purposefully or write '@include Xmedia-query' it errors), this is why I'm thinking it must be to do with the assets pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help someone else in the future - I've resolved this by figuring out I had a gem that also had:

```
@mixin media-query($media-query) {

}
```

This must have been causing some kind of conflict when compiling, shame Rails didn't flag it up for me.

I simply changed one of the `@mixins` to `@mixin mq($media-query)`